# Unconstrained requires-expression parameter

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Can I use constrained generic types inside C++20 constraints for a concept?  As an example, say I'd like to write a requirement that a candidate class `T` have a function `func` that can take an argument of any type that satisfies `std::ranges::range`:

```
template<typename T>
concept Foo = requires (T t, std::ranges:range s) {
    { t.func(a); } -> std::convertible_to<double>;
}
```

But GCC gives me an error message that a placeholder type cannot be used where I've put `std::ranges::range`.

Comment: What you want the concept to do looks Halt-hard.  Please be less vague?  "there exists a type I can pass to solve this constrait"?  Or did I misread you.

Comment: I have wondered if what I'm looking for would be too open-ended, essentially requiring the compiler to try "everything".  I'll need to give it some more thought to make it more precise what exactly I'm wanting

Comment: I guess what I'm looking for amounts to recursive constraint checking.  I could see cases of infinite recursion in cases of circular constraints or where for some other reason constraint checking would never reach an "atomic" type.  But that would only be a halting problem if we required the compiler to say whether the program is written with infinitely recursive constraints (aside from a compiler stack overflow).  But we don't ban recursion in, say, template metaprogramming--we rightly regard it as the programmer's job to avoid infinite recursion there, not the compiler's.

Comment: Incidentally, is someone able to say if it's for reasons related to recursive constraint checking that concept template parameters themselves cannot be constrained?

Comment: If your question is "is there any type `A` such that `A a` which satisfies these constraints (including no constraint at all!) that would make calling `t.func(a,b)` legal", then that is halt-hard.  There is a related question, which is "would every type `A` with satisfies the constraints I describe make `A a; t.func(a,b);` legal", which is not halt-hard, but has other issues.  Neither has much to do with recursion.  You keep saying syntax you want, but you need to be *very specific* about what you **need** that syntax *to do*.  (not "want", **need**)

Comment: Your question is at the edge of "halt-hard", and on the other side at the edge of "possible", and in the middle "you cannot do this in C++ using the constructs you want to use".  So you have to describe **exactly what you need**, not "I want something with this syntax that does stuff".  Because I can answer "this is halt-hard", "this is easy" or "you can't do this in C++ using the syntax you need", but it is a waste of time because I have no clue which is the answer to your actual question.

Comment: The waste of time is providing an answer that does not solve your problem; it is time that does not produce a useful answer, hence a waste of that resource in an objective sense.  I am obviously willing to spend time helping you, as I attempted to tell you what needs to be refined in your question in order to produce an answer to it that won't be a guess.  Your question is vague and needs refinement.  I will flag with that close reason and move on if you are uninterested in an answer.

Comment: I'm told that this article explains why I can't do what I want to.  I'll read it and as I understand, refine my question and try to make this useful to others who have this same question:

https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2020/08/10/concepts-cant-do-quantifiers/

Comment: Okay, upon reading the above article, I now see that what I was (trying) to ask fits the case you said is halt-hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have learned that, no, this is not possible.  The following article by Arthur O'Dwyer explains that in general, C++20 concepts cannot check mathematical quantifiers (https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2020/08/10/concepts-cant-do-quantifiers/)

> People frequently ask how to do things like this in C++20:
>
> > Make a concept Renderer that is satisfied if and only if t.render(u) is valid for all Printable types U. (From /r/cpp.)
>
> > Make a concept ValidSize that is satisfied if and only if t is convertible to some integral type U. (From the standard.)
>
> The key words above are “all” and “some.” In mathematics, these are known as the universal and existential quantifiers:
>
> Renderer ⇔ ∀U∈Printable: t.render(u) is well-formed
>
> ValidSize ⇔ ∃U∈Integral: U u = t; is well-formed
>
> C++20 Concepts do not support either quantifier.
>
> ...

The example in my question is identical to the `Renderer` example below, asking the concept to check that `T t` has `func` where `t.func(a)` is well-formed for all types `A` that satisfy `std::ranges::range`.  This uses a universal quantifer, which C++20 concepts cannot check.

---

As to whether or not such a thing could be possible for C++20 to support, from what I gather from comments such as [Unconstrained requires-expression parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66994909/unconstrained-requires-expression-parameter#comment118449318_66994909), this would not even be possible, in the sense that it reduces to solving the halting problem.  In direct conversation with the author of the article, Arthur O'Dwyer, he points out that at some point the constraints have to come down to a closed, fully specified list of concrete type:

> the only thing that'll help is to get rid of the quantifiers and deal with closed sets of types. For example, you can't do
>
> ```
> template<typename T>
> concept Foo = requires(T t) { t.func(a); };  // FOR-SOME-a; or FOR-ALL-a
> ```
>
> but you can do
>
> ```
> template<typename T, typename A>
> concept FooHelper = requires(T t, A a) { t.func(a); };
>
> template<typename T>
> concept Foo = FooHelper<T, int> || FooHelper<T, short> || FooHelper<T, char>;
>     // or, use &&
> ```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your looking a struct with an (declared only) `operator T ()` for a generic `T`

```
struct generic_argument
 {
   template <typename T>
   operator T () const;
 };
```

so you can pass it (inside a `decltype()`) for every expected argument and also a template argument.

So your concept (sorry... I simplify it removing the ranges argument) become (if I understand what do you want) something as

```
template<typename T>
concept Foo 
   = std::convertible_to<decltype(std::declval<T>().func(std::declval<generic_argument>())),
                         double>;
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <iostream>

struct A { double func (int a) { return a; } };
struct B { double not_func (long a) { return a; } };
struct C { std::string func (char) { return "abc"; } };
struct D { float func (auto) { return 1.0f; } };

struct E { double func (int a) { return a; }
           std::string func (char) { return "abc"; } };

struct generic_argument
 {
   template <typename T>
   operator T () const;
 };

template<typename T>
concept Foo 
   = std::convertible_to<decltype(std::declval<T>().func(std::declval<generic_argument>())),
                         double>;

template <Foo T>
void bar (T const &)
 { std::cout << "bar, Foo version\n"; }

template <typename T>
void bar (T const &)
 { std::cout << "bar, generic version\n"; }

int main()
 {
   bar(A{}); // print bar, Foo version
   bar(B{}); // print bar, generic version [no func() function]
   bar(C{}); // print bar, generic version [no convertible to double]
   bar(D{}); // print bar, Foo version
   bar(E{}); // print bar, generic version [two func() function]
 }
```

I'm in doubt regarding the `E` case: two `func()` methods, one only return a type convertible to `double`, from `bar(E{})` we get "bar, generic version".